# Windows(x64): OpenComputers Lua IDE

Tags: software-development, ide, plug-in, lua

I'm okay with using a plugin for Atom IDE or VSCode.
I'm looking for software that will allow me to edit The OpenComputers variant of Lua, so that I may write programs for said mod without having to be in game.

Comment: Is there any software that is similar to what you are looking for but not quite right? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the very thing I was looking for, so for others who can't find this: [Click here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=subtixx.opencomputerslua) for the VSCode plugin page-link. Note: **It's an extension of Visual Studio Code**, so you need Visual Studio Code for your OS in order to use the .VSIX you can get from the site.